# How can i optimize this linq function for calculating sum of "OrePreviste"?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, linq-to-sql, sum

the tableis this:

[image: Table]

The function in linq is this:

```
 public int CalcolaOreOccupate(string data)
    {
        int oreOccupate = 0;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            using (DatabaseDataContext contestoDB = new DatabaseDataContext())
            {
                contestoDB.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

                var elencoOre = (from db in contestoDB.Eventi
                                 where db.DataPrenotazione.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
                                 select db);

                foreach (var o in elencoOre)
                {
                    oreOccupate += o.OrePreviste;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
              /* ... othere code ... */
        }

        return oreOccupate;
    }
```

oreOccupate is sum of OrePreviste. I wanna get better function of mine. How can i do with linq?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Sum()` extension method:

```
var nowDate = DateTime.Now.Date; 
oreOccupate = contestoDB.Eventi
           .Where(x => x.DataPrenotazione.Date == nowDate)
           .Select(x => x.OrePreviste)
           .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
           .Sum();
```

When you do it like you show you basically get all your data from DB to your server to process and if you using MS SQL you can translate your query like i show to make all calculations in your Data base using LinqToSQL

As @enigmativity point in comments there is no need to init `DateTime.Now.Date` in separate variable since you using linqtosql and it will be translated to sql statement so called just once.

Comment: @Graham definatly you right 100%, it's my mistakes.

Comment: There's no need to put the `DateTime.Now.Date` outside of your query. Since the LINQ is being recompiled down to SQL calls there is no difference to being inline or not. It isn't called multiple times like it would be for Linq-To-Objects.

Comment: I wish @Graham would have left his comment. There is no need for anyone to delete comments that help the understanding of the question history.

Comment: @Enigmativity good point. I really don't know what OP using. He didn't plase linqtosql tag.

Comment: He's using `new DatabaseDataContext()` so we know it's using `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: whene oreOccupate is null?

Comment: @MarkusWerner just add `?? 0` after sum()

Comment: Don't work...it's:  You can not apply the operator ' ?? ' to operands of type ' int ' and ' int ' (it's translated from google translator from italian)

Comment: You shouldn't need `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` as calling `.Sum()` on an empty list returns `0`.

Comment: @Enigmativity if so there were no problems